# No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I am using 2 Weblogic data sources; In my XML configurations I have 2 persistence units, 2 entityManagerFactories, and 2 transactionManagers. The files are as follows:

**persistence.xml**:

```
<persistence-unit name="modelPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="orderPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
</persistence-unit>
```

**config.xml**:

```
<!-- transactionManagers -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="transactionManagerLegacy" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryLegacy" />
    </bean>

<!-- entityManagerFactory --> 
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceModel"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="modelPersistence" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
               <prop key="eclipselink.logging.level">FINE</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property> 
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>     

<!-- entityManagerFactoryLegacy --> 
        <bean id="entityManagerFactoryLegacy" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceOrder"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="orderPersistence" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
               <prop key="eclipselink.logging.level">FINE</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- data source 1-->
     <bean id="dataSourceModel" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" depends-on="model-datasource-jndi">
        <property name="jndiName" ref="model-datasource-jndi" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" /> 
    </bean> 

<!-- data source 2-->
     <bean id="dataSourceOrder" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" depends-on="order-datasource-jndi">
        <property name="jndiName" ref="order-datasource-jndi" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" /> 
    </bean> 

<!-- configure persistenceUnitManager -->
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
      <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
      <property name="dataSources">
        <map>
            <entry key="jdbc/MODEL-DS" value-ref="dataSourceModel"/>
            <entry key="jdbc/ORDER-DS" value-ref="dataSourceOrder"/> 
        </map>
      </property>
    </bean> 
    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.codingpedia.demo.repositories.ModelRepository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.codingpedia.demo.repositories.OrderRepository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryLegacy" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManagerLegacy"/>
```

**ModelRepository**:

```
@Repository ("ModelRepo")
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "modelPersistence")
public interface ModelRepository extends JpaRepository<Model, String> {}
```

**orderRepository**:

```
@Repository ("OrderRepo")
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "orderPersistence")
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Model, String> {}
```

Any suggestions on the correct annotation for handling multiple transaction managers? Am I missing something else? Other stack-overflow examples use DAOs which I have not found helpful as I am using repositories, model, and controller java files. I am also not using hibernate, which a lot of examples reference as well. Your insight is appreciated.

**I am receiving the following error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManagerLegacy,transactionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:370)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:271)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.codingpedia.demo.controller.BaseController.index(BaseController.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Comment: You are using Spring Data JPA I suggest a read of the documentation. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_custom_namespace_attributes. You need multiple `<jpa:repositories />` elements for each of the different repositories, each one tied to the correct entitymanagerfactory and transaction manager. Basically currently you are doing it plain wrong.

Comment: You need to configure spring-data-jpa correctly currently your configuration is wrong, that is also what the documentation is telling you. It has nothing to do with hibernate or not it is a matter of configuring Spring Data JPA correctly it needs to know which entity manger and transaction manager to use for which repositories. Also having 2 `<tx:annotation-driven />` elements isn't working you can only have one, or at least only one (the last one defined) will be useful.

Comment: You must have another repository element or `@EnableJpaRepositories` somewhere that is using the defaults or tries to do so. Probably in the config loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: The only 2 repositories I have are provided above; cant find any reason why the above configuration does not work. @M.Deinum

Comment: It isn't about the repositories it is about your configuration which must contain more `<jpa:repository />` elements or an `@EnableJpaRepositories` or it includes something else that has these enabled.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have checked and double checked, still cannot seem to figure what is triggering this error when everything else seems to be set up correctly...

Comment: Would Eclipse Dali be the reason this is still not working @M.Deinum? I came across an article that that possibly may be the reason why it is not working. I wonder if that bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use:

```
@Transactional("transactionManagerName")
```

See org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional (@Transactional) annotation javadoc:

```
/**
 * A qualifier value for the specified transaction.
 * <p>May be used to determine the target transaction manager,
 * matching the qualifier value (or the bean name) of a specific
 * {@link org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager}
 * bean definition.
 */
String value() default "";
```

Comment: I tried that annotation and still got the same error unfortunately.

Comment: So please try configuring transaction manager for all the repos (to see if it helps): <jpa:repositories base-package="some.package1" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager1"/>

Comment: Do you know of any additional resources?

Comment: @rgrebski Great answer works for me. Do you know by chance of any possibility to achieve the same with [`javax.transaction.Transactional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html) annotation?

Comment: @Mjar unfortunately there is no such option for javax.transaction.Transactional

Comment: perfect. it works for my case. i'm using multitenant with JPA. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case it should be:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerLegacy" />
```

cause that's the ID's of your beans.

If you want multiple datasource i suggest to read this: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: In this example you are using Spring's ORM JPA abstraction. There's no one hibernate JAR involved. yes, it is using hibernate under the hood, but you can change it to whatever you want. Also this tutorial shows how to achieve two datasources in Spring JPA

Comment: Don't focus on the hibernate fact (that is irrelevant) the important part is that it shows you (which you ignore) how to configure Spring Data JPA **correctly for multiple `EntityManagerFactory`s and `TransactionManager`s**.

Comment: Update: Thanks for the help guys, I am really new to this concept. @M.Deinum I added the 2 <jpa:repositories> statements in the application-context.xml and used the example and substituted the hibernate for Eclipse Link, still no luck.

Comment: Add your updated configuration to your question. There must be something else in your config triggering transaction manager lookup something which you haven't posted.

Comment: And add the full stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

Currently Dali only supports **one Persistence Unit** and **one Persistence XML file** per project. Other configurations can exist in a JPA project, but the validation and defaults processing may not be correct when multiple persistence units are used. Check out more information [here](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/gettingstarted.php).